# SNMP4J: SNMP Walk gives java.lang.NullPointerException: Context engine ID must not be null

Tags: java, snmp4j

I'm using SNMP4J to perform SNMPv3 Walk on an OID, but I get the below error,

java.lang.NullPointerException: Context engine ID must not be null

I'm able to get the responses successfully from SNMPv1, only v3 gives this error. Any help on this is highly appreciated

SNMP4J version: 2.5.3

Comment: "Context engine ID must not be null" so provide a non-null context engine ID. Possible hint: `ScopedPDU#setContextEngineID(OctetString)`

Comment: I'm able to do SNMP v3 Walk from a SNMP Browser without using ContextEngineID or ContextName. I'm able to use getBulk without ContextEngineID & ContextName not sure why only "Walk" requires this

Comment: I read in a comment elsewhere this -- "if there is no context engine ID provided, the security engine ID is used instead." I have my code as, 
    OctetString localEngineId = new 
    OctetString(MPv3.createLocalEngineID());USM usm = new USM(SecurityProtocols.getInstance(), localEngineId, 0);
    SecurityModels.getInstance().addSecurityModel(usm);
    snmp.getUSM().addUser(v3Username,
      new UsmUser(v3Username, v3AuthProtocol, v3AuthPhrase, v3PrivProtocol, v3PrivPhrase));

Comment: Since I'm doing a walk, I'm not using ScopedPDU to set the Context ID or Context name.    DefaultPDUFactory defaultPDUFactory = new DefaultPDUFactory();
  TreeUtils treeUtils = new TreeUtils(snmp, defaultPDUFactory);      
  events = treeUtils.getSubtree(getV3Target(), oid);

Comment: I'm really stuck on this one, anyone had luck with this one?... your help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Try to use `setContextEngineID` on the `DefaultPDUFactory`.

Comment: I was able to get it to work without using the ContextEngineID. I modified the line where I create defaultPDUFactory to "defaultPDUFactory = new DefaultPDUFactory(PDU.GETBULK);" The default constructor is using PDU.GET as the PDUType. TreeUtils.getSubtree specifies this - Gets a subtree with GETNEXT (SNMPv1) or GETBULK (SNMP2c, SNMPv3) operations from the specified target synchronously.

Comment: Good, maybe you could add a self answer and accept it

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get it to work without using the ContextEngineID or ContextName.

I was creating the DefaultPDUFactory without specifying the PDUType, and the default constructor uses PDU.GET as the PDUType. While reading TreeUtils.getSubtree comment which mentioned "Gets a subtree with GETNEXT (SNMPv1) or GETBULK (SNMP2c, SNMPv3) operations from the specified target synchronously." I realized I had to set the PDUType to GETBULK.

I was able to do a successful 'Walk' using SNMPv3 after setting the PDUType to GETBULK when creating the DefaultPDUFactory object.

```
DefaultPDUFactory defaultPDUFactory = new DefaultPDUFactory(PDU.GETBULK); 
TreeUtils treeUtils = new TreeUtils(snmp, defaultPDUFactory); 
events = treeUtils.getSubtree(getV3Target(), oid)
```